# How can I get VS2008 to use debug version of DLL instead of running it from System32?

Tags: visual-studio-2008, dll

I recently inherited some C++ DLL projects from another programmer who left the company.  I have very little experience in this area.

These DLLs are normally installed into \Windows\System32, and are used by other programs - both C++ and C#.  These DLLs are not registered.

I've created a solution that includes both the C++ DLL project, and one of the C# projects that uses it.  I've also set up the Project Dependencies appropriately.

When I run the C# program from VS, it is using the DLLs in System32, not the debug versions from the VS project's debug directory.

As a workaround, I've been manually copying the DLLs and PDBs to System32, but this is a pain, and also contaminates the installation of older releases of the software.

How can I get VS2008 to use the debug DLLs?

Comment: In your solution folder, do you see a directory named Debug with the C++ DLLs and another directory named bin\Debug with the C# DLLs and EXE?

Comment: I see a Debug dir with the C++ DLLs.  Don't see a bin\Debug with C# files - probably because we are redirecting output to a common build directory (via Project Build Tab > Output path)

Answer (score 0):

I modified my C++ project to put the DLLs in the same common build folder that the C# programs are being built in.

C++ setting is in:

> Configuration Properties > Linker > General > Output File

The C# programs are now finding the DLL, but this probably means I'll have change my installer build process, so it's not ideal.